# Bing Maps GPXRouteViewerSample won't run - having a debugger attached is unexpected?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, bing-maps

When I try to run GPXRouteViewerSample, it stops on this line in App.g.i.cs:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached) Debugger.Break();
```

...and I get the err msg:

*Error  1   The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)    C:\Users\Clay\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Samples\bingMapsCSharpGPXRouteViewerSample\GPXRouteViewerSample\MainPage.xaml    12  9   GPXRouteViewerSample*

I don't get why they would want it to break if a debugger is attached - IOW, you can't run it from Visual Studio, or..???

### MORE INFO

When I open the sample app, the WPF/XAML design surface says, "Cannot create an instance of "Map" But then when I enter my Bing Maps key in the appropriate place (Credentials="") it displays.

Then at runtime, though, when the error occurs on the "debug break" line, the surface/canvas shows that same error. Is it accepting the credentials at design-time but not at runtime?

Here are the details of the exception (this is actually from a different sample (Landmark Events), but I'm sure it's the same problem, as it's dying in the same place):

*Exception: Cannot Create an Instance of Map
Stack Trace:
at 
Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.InstanceBuilderOperations.Instant
iateType(Type type, Boolean supportInternal)
   at 
Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.Instanti
ateTargetType(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at 
Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.Instanti
ate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at 
Microsoft.Expression.WindowsXamlPlatform.InstanceBuilders.FrameworkElementInstan
ceBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at 
Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ViewNodeManager.CreateInstance
(IInstanceBuilder builder, ViewNode viewNode)
Inner Exception:
TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an 
invocation.
Stack Trace:
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, 
Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, 
Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
COMException: The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from 
HRESULT: 0x8007007F)*

Comment: the break code is in the context of an unhandled exception which is the real problem - do you have a call stack?  The sample is working ok for me.

Comment: I'll add on to my original post.